# LaTeX package for keeping track of content in paper preliminaries

Tags: macros, packages

In scientific writing, there is often a section called "preliminaries" in papers providing essential definitions that are used later in the paper but only very briefly explained because there are contributions of the paper. They, in a sense, contain the "boring" stuff that needs to be there and mostly introduces the notation used in the rest of the paper.

Parts in the preliminaries are often added because they are used in another section of the paper. While the paper is being edited heavily by possibly multiple authors using a version control system, it can happen that some parts of the preliminaries are no longer needed.

This could be detected by adding something like `\promise{basketweaving}` in the paragraph where a concept is used, and `\keeppromise{basketweaving}` in the preliminaries sentence defining the "basket weaving" concept. Then, the LaTeX compiler could warn about unkept promises. Similarly, a list of unused kept promises could be automatically added into draft versions of the document.

Is there such a package? When restructuring a piece of text shortly before a deadline, preliminaries can easily become out of sync with the rest of the paper, while the authors can be expected not to split promises, or kept promises from their respective sentences/paragraphs -- especially unused kept promises would be useful to detect.

Comment: Shameless plug: you could take a look at `zref-check`. I use it to keep track of statements such as "as mentioned above", "as will be discussed later" and things of the sort. It seems you could do something similar for your needs.

Comment: @gusbrs That package seems to do most of the requested job - since you are the author: is there a way to adapt it to get a list of zlabels never referred to?

Comment: I was thinking the other way around. In the place where you are writing the part of your text which requires some sort of "preliminaries", you set a `\zctarget`. Then you write the corresponding preliminary, and with it a `\zcheck`. You may use the check `after`, but in your case, you can leave the check empty, and you'll only get an "undefined label" warning if you ever remove the part of the text which had required that preliminary (and thus the `\zctarget`).

Comment: @gusbrs Ah, interesting idea. It requires a bit of manual work whenever one usage of a definition is removed, though. But certainly doable (for most papers, I guess)

Comment: Well, yes, the whole idea you proposed requires a certain "discipline". `zref-check` is within its spirit, I think. True, for the relative position checks which are its mainstay, its easier to manage, with options to silence them globally or individually. In your case, you'd be relying in undefined labels, which is harder to ignore. But, in the end, you do have a tool to keep track and make sure things match. Besides, the "manual work" you referred to is exactly "removing the unwanted preliminary which is no longer needed".